# Add filename before first occurrence of a character in all lines for all files in a given folder

Tags: python, bash, awk, text-processing

I have a folder full of files with lines which look like this:

**S149.sh**

```
sox preaching.wav _001 trim 889.11 891.23
sox preaching.wav _002 trim 891.45 893.92
sox preaching.wav _003 trim 1599.95 1606.78
```

And I want to add the filename without its extension (which is `S149`) right before the first occurrence of the `_` character in every line, so that it ends up looking like this:

```
sox preaching.wav S149_001 trim 889.11 891.23
sox preaching.wav S149_002 trim 891.45 893.92
sox preaching.wav S149_003 trim 1599.95 1606.78
```

And I want to automatically do this for every *.sh file in a given folder.

How do I achieve that with either bash (this includes awk, grep, sed, etc.) or python? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where `S149` is the file extension here.

Comment: @hek2mgl: `S149` is _the filename without its extension._

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf said what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, using `ed`, the standard editor and a loop:

```
for i in *.sh; do
    printf '%s\n' ",g/_/ s/_/${i%.sh}&/" w q | ed -s -- "$i"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${i%.sh}` expands to `$i` where the suffix `.sh` is removed.

The `ed` commands are, in the case `i=S149.sh`:

```
,g/_/ s/_/S149&/
w
```

`,g/_/` marks all lines containing an underscore and `s/_/S149&/` replaces the underscore by `S149_`. Then `w` writes the file.

Comment: `++` for good'ol `ed`, I am aware of some basic usages, but can you explain 1) the reason for `,` before `g` and 2) `space` after `,g/_/` and how is this controlling the replacement for first occurrence alone and not other `_` in the line

Comment: @Inian: 1. `,` means the whole buffer; it's a synonym for `1,$`; 2. space after `,g/_/` is irrelevant, only here for cosmetic purposes; 3. only the first `_` is substituted since the `s` command is not flagged by a trailing `g`: it's _not_ `s/_/S149&/g` (the flag `g` would replace all non-overlapping occurrences—`g` for _global_).

Comment: Makes sense now! Cheers!

Comment: Just another clarification, to test it in `Vim` maybe if I type `,g/_/ s/<pat1>/<pat2>/` it is not actually replacing when run from the command interface  `:`

Comment: @Inian: `vim` uses `ex`, not `ed`, and in `ex` the full buffer is `%`, whereas `,` is the current line, synonym of `.,.`.

Comment: Just an `FYI`, the `ex` equivalent would be `printf '%s\n' "%g/_/s/_/${i%.sh}&/" w q | ex -s "$i"`

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` version:

```
for i in *.sh; do
    sed -i "s/_/${i%.*}_/g" "$i"
done
```

`${i%.*}` expands to the filename minus the extension used by the in-place replacement operation.

Comment: @EdMorton: well, if the filename contains `&` or `\<digit>`, then the script, when executed eventually, will fail too, even with the `awk` in your answer (not mentioning spaces, newlines, quotes, dollars, backslashes in general and other shell metacharacters). The problem is that we're transforming data into code. It's the whole design and strategy of OP that's not good.

Comment: @EdMorton: yeah, the awk will work, but then the result will be useless anyway. And actually, a shell loop would be superior in this case since it would be trivial to properly escape all the characters `:D`.

Comment: Quoting would be done using `printf '%q'`. Adding single quotes wouldn't be enough, in case filename contains single quoted. [`sox` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox).

Comment: Escaping if that's how you call it (and that's how I called it earlier too—it's called _quoting_ in `printf`'s help page). To be fully safe, `printf '%q'` would be the way to go. Single quotes are not enough in case filename contains single quotes.

Comment: The OP says "I have a folder full of files with lines which look like this:

S149.sh" - in that case the sed solution works.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for inplace editing:

```
awk -i inplace 'FNR==1{f=gensub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",1,FILENAME)} {$3=f$3} 1' *.sh
```

If you're considering using a shell loop instead, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Who mentioned considering a shell loop to process text?

Comment: It's a common approach that newbies think is reasonable so best to give them the facts.

Comment: I don't even see how they would do that. Using a temporary file and using `sed` on each line?

Comment: `for f in *.sh; do while read x y z rest; do echo "$x $y ${f%%.*}$z $rest"; done < "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f"; done` or similar with the usual "no external tools required" statement as if that's a good thing.

Comment: Btw, you're not quite answering OP's requirement here. OP wants to replace the first occurrence of `_`, not the third field of each line.

Comment: I understand but we often have people ask how to implement solution X because that's how they think they need to solve problem Y rather than asking for a solution to problem Y. This is a simpler solution to what I believe is the OPs real problem, Y.

Answer (score 1):

@Ruran- In case you do not have an awk which could do Input_file editing while reading the Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
 awk '(FILENAME != P && P && Q){close(P);system("mv " Q OFS P)} {Q=P=FILENAME;sub(/\..*/,X,Q);sub(/_/,Q"&");print > Q;} END{system("mv " Q OFS P)}' *.sh
```

Logic, behind is simple it is changing the first occurrence of _(char) and then it is keeping the new formatted lines into a tmp file while reading next Input_file it is renaming that temp file into the previous Input_file.

Also one more point which I have not seen here in above posts it as we are using *.sh so let's say you have thousands of Input_files then code may give error which is because of too many Input_files will be opened and we are NOT closing the files, so I am closing them too, let me know if this helps you.

A non-one liner form of solution too as follows.

```
awk '(FILENAME != P && P && Q){
                                close(P);
                                system("mv " Q OFS P)
                              }
                              {
                                Q=P=FILENAME;
                                sub(/\..*/,X,Q);
                                sub(/_/,Q"&");
                                print > Q;
                              }
     END                      {
                                system("mv " Q OFS P)
                              }
    ' *.sh
```

Comment: The possible too many open files issue isn't mentioned in my answer because it cannot happen when using GNU awk as gawk manages the number of simultaneously open files internally and it's not mentioned in the other answers because they handle each file individually in a loop. Your system commands should be `system("mv -- \047" Q "\047 \047" P "\047")`, btw to avoid failing when the file name contains spaces or globbing characters and don't use an uninitialised variable `X` in place of a NULL string `""` - it just obfuscates your code and makes it more error-prone.

Comment: Finally - restructure so `Q=P=FILENAME;
                                sub(/\..*/,X,Q);
                                sub(/_/,Q"&");` only happens once when the input file is first open (i.e. in a `FILENAME!=P` or `FNR==1` block) so you are doing that once per file instead of doing it once for every line of input.